# $lookup for nested collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here I am looking to join nested joins with multiple collections:

Below are the schemas of three collections ie USER, POST, and COMMENTS

```
 const Users = new mongoose.Schema ({
      firstName: {type: String, default: null},
      lastName: {type: String, default: null},
      city:{type: String, default: null},
      country:{type: String, default: null},
      registerTime: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
      email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
      password: {type: String, default: null},
      token: {type: String, default: null},
      friends: [{status: String, userid: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ftype:String}],
      userId:{type: String, default: null}

    });


const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

    title: {type: String},
    body: {type: String},
    date: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
    tags:{type: String},
    flag:{type:String},
    _author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}

});

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    comment: {type: String},
    postby: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    date: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
    postid:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}

});
```

> I have created below Query to get lists of all Posts with user details
>    (join from the user) who posted that post.  --Done
>
> Get all Comments specific to each post -- Done

Up to here, I am successfully able to make Left join for two the documents.I am using the following query and I get the result.

```
Posts.aggregate([  
                {"$match": {'_flag': "PUBLISHED"}} ,
                { $sort: { date: -1 } },
                { $lookup: { 
                             from: 'users',
                             localField: '_author',
                             foreignField:'_id', 
                             as:'userDetail'
                            }
                }, // post+ user document

                { $lookup: {
                            from: 'comments', 
                            localField: '_id',
                            foreignField:'postid',
                            as:'commentdata'
                            }
                }  // post+ comments
])
```

Here The result is :

```
{
"status": "Post Listing",
    "posts": [{
        "_id": "5aae21fe58658522243ba9e3",
        "title": "hello zulias;s",
        "tags": "dsadas",
        "flag": "p",
        "_author": "87fe4052dd86c409576fe3e8bc8e6734a024e34d1ee4e841",
        "body": "<p>dsadasda</p>\n",
        "date": "2018-03-18T08:23:26.870Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "userDetail":[{
            "fname": "anurag",
            "lname": "sads",
            "email": "zudsadalia@gmail.com"
        }],

        "commentdata": [{
            "_id": "5aafc8046aa1ec34ac7d8163",
            "postby": "5a993b12303c86133437c681",
            "postid": "5aae21fe58658522243ba9e3",
            "comment": "commment first, ",
            "date": "2018-03-19T14:24:04.231Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5aafc8076aa1ec34ac7d8164",
            "postby": "5a993b12303c86133437c681",
            "postid": "5aae21fe58658522243ba9e3",
            "comment": "commment first, \nCom ",
            "date": "2018-03-19T14:24:07.760Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
         {
            "_id": "5ab26b07d256913bf8de1cc4",
            "postby": "5a993b2e303c86133437c682",
            "postid": "5aae21fe58658522243ba9e3",
            "comment": "Dasdas",
            "date": "2018-03-21T14:24:07.176Z",
            "__v": 0
        }],

    },

    {
        "_id": "5aad5f207ecf7842bc4ab0f2",
        "title": "sdas",
        "tags": "dsad",
        "flag": "p",
        "_author": "87fe4052dd86c75e576fe3e8bc8e6734a024e34d1ee4e842",
        "body": "<p>sda</p>\n",
        "date": "2018-03-17T18:32:00.194Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "commentdata": [],
        "userDetail":[{
            "fname": "zulia",
            "lname": "Rai",
            "email": "zulia@gmail.com"
        }],
    },

}
```

The issue is, in above result, each post have **Commentdata** array in which all comments are there for a perticular post. Each comment inside **Commentdata** is associated with the single user who posted that comment. So here I want Username from user table for each comment.
    ie

```
"commentdata": [{
                "_id": "5aafc8046aa1ec34ac7d8163",
                "postby": "5a993b12303c86133437c681",  // need name of this user from user table
                "postid": "5aae21fe58658522243ba9e3",
                "comment": "commment first, ",
                "date": "2018-03-19T14:24:04.231Z",
                "__v": 0,
                fname": "zulia", // added after join 
            },
```

Comment: And whats your question is exactly?

Comment: I want to get Commented data with user details so how can I join these both collections ie commented data array and User collection.

Comment: Please post all your 3 collections data set without which its impossible to replicate

Comment: Rahul: please check now I have reframed my issue again.  hope you will get it now. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me the 3 **data sets** you are using? not the schema..

Comment: share me ur email I'll posted there ??

Comment: post ur sample data sets here, so that anybody can look into your question and provide suggestions.